# Setting em is not relative

Tags: css, fonts

If I dont set my font size, or I set it to 1em I get a computed font size of 16px.
If I set it to .875em I get a computed size of 7px 
That doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: Do you have HTML and CSS to back up this assertion?

Comment: In case of .875em i get 14px.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GeHNW/

Comment: You are probably setting font size on nested elements so that the effects cumulate. Show us your code.

Comment: The problem was that I set the font size in a parent div. Not sure why that mattered, but when I changed it to the right one it worked.

Comment: To expand on Jukka's comment: consider using `rem`s instead of `em`s to bypass that problem (see [this guide](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem)).

Answer (score 0):

Its calculation depending on font size set in body tag or browsers default that is 16px size. See below link for detail.
http://v1.jontangerine.com/silo/css/pixels-to-ems/